# Jersey validation on Client side

Tags: jackson, jersey, bean-validation, moxy

We're using **Payara 4** server with **Jersey** version 2.22.2, which is using **Moxi** for *XML* and *JSON* serialization/deserialization. But if necessary we can switch from *Moxy* to *Jackson*.

On the server side, meaning in our resource layer that receives the REST requests, we're using *Java Bean Validation* to validate the requests.

I want to know what is the best way to validate request/response on **client's side**, meaning when we're using Jersey to send REST requests to external system and then I want to validate the response we got.

In below guide it says "Jersey does not support Bean Validation on the client at the moment."
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e13692

Moxy is actually running automatically Bean Validation on request/response but only if I'm using XML. For Json it skips the Bean Validation.

Is the only way is to switch to Jackson, or I'm missing something?

Comment: You could wrap the Jersey client and add bean validation there.

Comment: Thanks, it is an interesting idea. I was hoping to find some "out of the box" solution that is integrated already inside Jersey, as this seems very basic thing - client's side validation.

Comment: If you use JSF as your front end, see https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/bean.xhtml

Comment: Worse case, you can manually validate using the [bean validation library](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-validating-bean-constraints) that comes with the Bean Validation support.